# Classify a sentence into multiple categories

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk, text-classification

A beginner in NLTK and Scikit-learn here. I want to be able to classify a given sentence(or even a paragraph) into a group of categories. By categories, I don't mean only two categories like spam and not spam or good sentiment and bad sentiment, meaning its multiple(more than two) categories to choose from. Please help me in choosing the simplest algorithm for solving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In fact it is impossible to tell which algorithm is best or efficient without looking at the data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By the tag you used in the post I see that you know about `machine learning`... This is a good way for doing this project.

What you are going to need is a decent amount of sample data, that is, a table of text (sample sentences, paragraphs, whatever...) and then a column that states the category it is in.

What you do is `train` the program, to look for patterns in the sample text, and if you have enough sample data, you can then `analyze` text, and have the program output what category it is.

You could use [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) as your machine learning framework.

I suggest you start with a few simpler projects to get an idea for how machine learning works and what works best.

Comment: So that means is if I have enough categorized data then simple Frequency Distribution of words in sentences will be enough to classify data?. Thanks for replying.

Comment: I have never attempted something like that... but I can't see it being too difficult to test. 

From my understanding of it... yes... it should.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right , you're trying to perform a topic modelling on your data set .
As far as I'm concerned , you can use LDA (Latent Dirichlet allocation ) , but you'll have the obligation to specify the number of topics , you can do several test to find the appropriate value of number of topics  . 
This is an example of LDA performed using python and  demonstrates how to inspect a model of a subset of the Reuters news dataset . The input below, X, is a document-term matrix .

```
 >>> import numpy as np
>>> import lda
>>> X = lda.datasets.load_reuters()
>>> vocab = lda.datasets.load_reuters_vocab()
>>> titles = lda.datasets.load_reuters_titles()
>>> X.shape
(395, 4258)
>>> X.sum()
84010
>>> model = lda.LDA(n_topics=20, n_iter=1500, random_state=1)
>>> model.fit(X)  # model.fit_transform(X) is also available
>>> topic_word = model.topic_word_  # model.components_ also works
>>> n_top_words = 8
>>> for i, topic_dist in enumerate(topic_word):
...     topic_words = np.array(vocab)[np.argsort(topic_dist)][:-n_top_words:-1]
...     print('Topic {}: {}'.format(i, ' '.join(topic_words)))
Topic 0: british churchill sale million major letters west
Topic 1: church government political country state people party
Topic 2: elvis king fans presley life concert young
Topic 3: yeltsin russian russia president kremlin moscow michael
Topic 4: pope vatican paul john surgery hospital pontiff
Topic 5: family funeral police miami versace cunanan city
Topic 6: simpson former years court president wife south
Topic 7: order mother successor election nuns church nirmala
Topic 8: charles prince diana royal king queen parker
Topic 9: film french france against bardot paris poster
Topic 10: germany german war nazi letter christian book
Topic 11: east peace prize award timor quebec belo
Topic 12: n't life show told very love television
Topic 13: years year time last church world people
Topic 14: mother teresa heart calcutta charity nun hospital
Topic 15: city salonika capital buddhist cultural vietnam byzantine
Topic 16: music tour opera singer israel people film
Topic 17: church catholic bernardin cardinal bishop wright death
Topic 18: harriman clinton u.s ambassador paris president churchill
Topic 19: city museum art exhibition century million churches
```